# How can I sense the output voltage of an H-bridge using a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, peltier, 741-opamp

I have developed a circuit to control a Peltier cell using a H-bridge controller with two PWM signals. The brain of the whole project is a PIC24F, the circuit works (in this project I usually change the polarity of the Peltier cell, it is important to know this) but now I want to be able to measure the output voltage that reaches the Peltier, since if I take the current duty cycle and multiply it by V<sub>CC</sub> I get a voltage that is not close to the real output voltage, what circuit would you advise me to use? I thought about using an opamp and thus obtain a low voltage square wave and the PIC calculates the average voltage of the square wave, but the frequency of the wave is 2.5 kHz and I am not very sure if it can do it efficiently.

Can you help me with this? Since I have a couple of doubts, the first is that since the polarity of the output of the H-bridge changes, if I assume a fixed node as "GND" then sometimes the opamp will show a positive or negative signal and if I use a rectifier I run two risks:

1. I would lose some voltage in the diode (although V<sub>CC</sub> is 24 I feel that 0.3 V could be a lot, I don't know).
2. Even if I manage to obtain a positive output in the op-amp I would not know if the voltage is positive or negative. I am using the following references: AVCC = V<sub>CC</sub> and AVSS = GND.

I hope you can help me, thank you all and HAPPY NEW YEAR to everyone... ;D

Comment: Does this have a PWM filter or is it direct drive? At least one ADC channel is available, right? Why does measuring Vcc not equate?

Comment: Can you post a schematic?

Comment: driving a Peltier with a PWM instead of an analog voltage difference is **less efficient** (wastes more power for the same heat pumped), so it is advicable to combine the half bridges with an LC filter in the long term